# SET CET Time to CET only

Tags: jquery, html, time

My dates coming from JSON file which are CET time in millisecond and I want to get those in CET only. But my code is converting that dates to GMT. I don't want them to be in GMT. I want CET only. Please suggest! This is my code. I have not set anywhere to convert it to GMT, it is converting by default.

```
myData = data;
myData.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = new Date(d.date);
  d.name = +d.name;
  console.log(d.date,"Gt date");
});
```

Comment: Please add the JSON file that is being read, or at least the format of the date that you are reading.

Comment: 1459548000000          my date format

Answer (score 1):

`Date` objects do not have an inherent timezone -- they will be displayed in the user's local zone -- but on creation they assume GMT unless otherwise specified.

You should not be storing date data based on a non-GMT timezone, because you then will have to deal with the nightmare that is daylight savings; far better to store everything in GMT and then convert to local time at the display step.  You should *especially* not be storing simple numeric ms-past-epoch times as non-GMT, because all sane code (or future maintainers of your code) will assume that it's GMT.

When creating a date object you can either specific that it is in CET (but are you sure some of that data isn't CEST?) or simply do the conversion yourself by subtracting an hour before calling `new Date()` on it.  In your case, since you're already in ms, it's going to be easier to just subtract the hour.

Dates read from a `Date` object will be displayed in the local timezone by default -- note that if you have two users in two different timezones they'll see different zones on the same date.  Usually this is what you want anyway.

Comment: so how can i mention this is my code..how can i subtract an hour

Comment: An hour is 60 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds. So you can subtract 3600000 from the CET timestamp to get UTC. (Unless you have to consider about daylight saving time)
 `new Date(1459548000000 - 3600000).toLocaleString('en-GB', {timeZone: 'Europe/Paris'})`

Comment: bUT i dont want to hardcode my date..it will come from json

Comment: Why would you hardcode your date? Nobody has suggested that.

Comment: Yep, as @HåkenLid suggested, you can read the stored ms value from your JSON, subtract 3600000 to remove an hour, and pass the resulting value into a `new Date()`; there is no hardcoding involved (other than the timezone offset).  But I would *strongly strongly* recommend you convert the data you've already stored into UTC now, rather than continuing to store times tied to a particular timezone, because you're guaranteed to have daylight savings time related errors as time goes on. (Europe is currently UTC+2, not UTC+1, note! Which one have you been storing?)